# Проблема с отправкой через PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

У меня PHPmailer отправляет письма пользователям через цикл, но получается что от отправляет одно письмо всем пользователям вместо каждому уникальное. Он просто добавляет емайлы через запятую в получатели и все...

Как это поправить можно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно это вам поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451680/phpmailer-foreach-loop

```
 $mail->ClearAddresses(); // remove previous email addresses
```